# Smarty Where Clause Not Filtering Data

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, where-clause

I am trying to Display all Data Based on a `Where Statement` but it is showing all the data from the table. Below is my `account.php` file code

```
$sql = "SELECT Country,COUNT(*) as count, ROUND(100.0*COUNT(ip)/(SELECT     count(ip)  FROM ip_ptc),2) as percentage  FROM ip_ptc GROUP BY Country


UNION ALL

SELECT 'SUM' ip, COUNT(ip) as sum,'100%'
FROM ip_ptc  WHERE ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']); 

$result = mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
$data[] = $row; # $data is the array created for use in the Smarty template. 
} 
$smarty->assign('data', $data); 
//showing data for addstate

$smarty->assign("file_name", "ptcmaxclicks.tpl");
$smarty->display("account.tpl");
$db->close();
exit();
```

Checking to url it is passing `gc['aid']` accordingly but showing all the data from the table not according to `gc['aid']` and in my `account.tpl` file i  have following code

```
{foreach from=$data item=item key=key} 
<tr>
   <td>{$item.Country}</td> <td>{$item.count}</td> <td>{$item.percentage}</td> 
<tr> 
{/foreach}
```

what's wrong i am doing? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `WHERE` clause only applies to the second `SELECT`. You need to add it to the first `SELECT` too i.e.:

```
$sql = "SELECT Country, COUNT(*) as count, 
            ROUND(100.0*COUNT(ip)/(SELECT count(ip)  FROM ip_ptc),2) as percentage
        FROM ip_ptc 
        WHERE ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']) . 
       " GROUP BY Country
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'SUM' ip, COUNT(ip) as sum,'100%'
        FROM ip_ptc
        WHERE ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']);
```

Comment: I am outputting SUM as a text and showing a sum value of all records at bottom of all row. But after using your code it is now giving a syntex errror ' syntax to use near 'BY Country UNION ALL SELECT 'SUM' ip, COUNT(ip) as sum,'100%' FROM ip' at line 1'

Comment: Hi Mithu, I forgot a space before 'GROUP'. Try it now.

Comment: can you help me on one more point in SELECT Country, COUNT(*) as count, 
            ROUND(100.0*COUNT(ip)/(SELECT count(ip)  FROM ip_ptc),2) as percentage  how can i add a where clause in SELECT count(ip)  FROM ip_ptc

Comment: Just put it in the subquery `...ROUND(100.0*COUNT(ip)/(SELECT count(ip) FROM ip_ptc WHERE ad_id=" .  $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid'] . "), 2)...`

Comment: putting like so it is showing an error in my text editor

Comment: showing the error in last line of whole statement WHERE ad_id=" . $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['aid']);  after putting this

Comment: Sorry, left off a `)` after `->gc['aid']`